# why in an 'if' statement 'then' has to be in the next line in bash?

Tags: bash, if-statement

`if` is followed by `then` in bash but I don't understand why `then` cannot be used in the same line like `if [...] then` it has to be used in the next line. Does that remove some ambiguity from the code? or bash is designed like that? what is the underlying reason for it?

I tried to write `if` and `then` in the same line but it gave the error below:

```
./test: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token \`fi'
./test: line 6: \`fi'
```

the code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $1 -gt 0 ] then
echo "$1 is positive" 
fi
```

Comment: BTW, this isn't a *bash* language decision -- it's part of the [POSIX shell command language](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) specification, so other POSIX-compliant shells implement the same syntax.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It has to be preceded by a separator of some description, not *necessarily* on the next line<sup>(a)</sup>. In other words, to achieve what you want, you can simply use:

```
if [[ $1 -gt 0 ]] ; then
    echo "$1 is positive"
fi
```

As an aside, for one-liners like that, I tend to prefer:

```
[[ $1 -gt 0 ]] && echo "$1 is positive"
```

But that's simply because I prefer to see as much code on screen as possible. It's really just a style thing which you can freely ignore.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The reason for this can be found in the `Bash` manpage (my emphasis):

> RESERVED WORDS: Reserved words are words that have a special meaning to the shell. The following words are recognized as reserved when unquoted and either ***the first word of a simple command*** (see SHELL GRAMMAR below) or the third word of a `case` or `for` command:
>
> `! case  coproc  do done elif else esac fi for function if in select then until while { } time [[ ]]`

Note that, though that section states it's the "first word of a simple command", the manpage seems to contradict itself in the referenced `SHELL GRAMMAR` section:

> A simple command is a sequence of optional variable assignments followed by blank-separated words and redirections, and terminated by a control operator. ***The first word specifies the command to be executed,*** and is passed as argument zero.

So, whether you consider it part of the next command or a separator of some sort is arguable. What is *not* arguable is that it needs a separator of some sort (newline or semicolon, for example) before the `then` keyword.

The manpage doesn't go into *why* it was designed that way but it's *probably* to make the parsing of commands a little simpler.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the keyword `then` isn't *in* a simple command; it *separates* the command list forming the condition form the command list forming the body. If `then` appears on the same line, the semicolon is necessary to terminate the command list (in place of the newline that is no longer there). (Although I see where the man page is coming from, and it accurately describes how the parser performs the disambiguation, I'm not sure it's the clearest way to explain it.)

Comment: (For example, you can write `if someCommand; someOtherCommand; then ...`; `then`, if seen in command position, acts as sort of a "super terminator" distinct from an ordinary list terminator.)

Comment: @chepner, I think I see your point, and it appears the manpage is not fully consistent. The bit I quoted seems to clearly state that the `then` is part of the simple command but she `SHELL GRAMMAR` section it references implies not. Will update the answer accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Here's another way to explain the need for a line break or semicolon before `then`: the thing that goes between `if` and `then` is a command (or sequence of commands); if the `then` just came directly after the command without a delimiter, it'd be ambiguous whether it should be treated as a shell keyword or just an argument to the command.

For instance, this is a perfectly valid command:

```
echo This prints a phrase ending with then
```

...which prints "This prints a phrase ending with then". Now, consider this one:

```
if echo This prints a phrase ending with then
```

should that print "This prints a phrase ending with then" and look for a `then` keyword later on, or should it just print "This prints a phrase ending with" and treat the `then` as a keyword?

In order to settle this ambiguity, shell syntax says it should treat "then" as an argument to `echo`, and in order to get it treated as a keyword you need a command delimiter (line break or semicolon) to mark the end of the command.

Now, you might think that your `if` condition `[ $1 -gt 0 ]`, already has a perfectly good delimiter, namely the `]`. But in shell syntax, that's really just an argument to the `[` command (yes, that's a command). Try this command:

```
[ 1 -gt 0 ] then
```

...and you'll probably get an error like "-bash: [: missing ']'", because the `[` command checked its last argument to make sure it was "]", found that it was "then" instead, and panicked.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it helps to understand why this is so by way of a few examples. The argument to `if` is a *sequence* of commands; so you can say e.g.

```
if read -r -p "What is your name?" name
    [ "$name" -eq "tripleee" ]
then
    echo "I kneel before thee"
fi
```

or even a complex compound like

```
while read -r -p "Favorite number?" number
    case $number in
        42) true; break;;
        *) false;;
    esac
do
    echo "Review your preferences, then try again"
 done
```

This extremely powerful but potentially confusing feature of the shell is probably one of its most misunderstood constructs. The ability to pass a sequence of commands to the flow control statements can make for very elegant scripts, but is often missed entirely (see e.g. [Why is testing "$?" to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern))

Answer (score -2):

If it helps, you can use semi-colons

```sh
if [ $1 -gt 0 ]; then
echo "$1 is positive" 
fi

# or even

if [ $1 -gt 0 ]; then echo "$1 is positive"; fi
```

As for *why*, it helps me to think of `if`, `then`, `else`, and `fi` as bash commands, and just like all other commands, they need to be at the start of a line (or after a semi-colon).

Comment: It does *not* help to think of them as commands, since you *cannot* write something like `if [ $1 -gt 0]; then; echo "$1 is positive"`. `if` et al. are *keywords* that together form a single compound command.

Comment: it doesn't help *you*

Comment: boo, hiss re: describing outright misapprehensions as "helpful", even when they can demonstrably lead to errors. A "command" is a specific thing with a formal definition in the POSIX sh syntax spec.