# remove an alias if it exists in zsh

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, zsh, alias

I'm trying to remove an alias set to the keyword clear in zsh, but first i would like to check if it exists.
here is what i've tried:

```sh
if whence -w clear | grep "alias" then
  unalias clear
fi
```

but I can't figure out how to make if work with the output of the piline.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why in an 'if' statement 'then' has to be in the next line in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57834136/why-in-an-if-statement-then-has-to-be-in-the-next-line-in-bash) (The question mentions Bash, but the answer applies to `sh` in general, including Zsh)

Comment: @LuanVitor: Aside from the missing semicolon in your code, the `if` is unnecessary: If the alias exists, you want to remove it, if it doesn't exist, it doesn't matter if you try to remove it. Hence, I would not use an `if` at all, but simply write `unalias clear 2>/dev/null || true`. The sole purpose of using `|| true` is to allow your code to run even if `set -e` is in effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you forget a semicolon after `grep "alias"`? The following works just fine in zsh.

```
% alias clear=something
% alias
clear=something
% if whence -w clear | grep "alias"; then
      unalias clear
  fi
  clear: alias
% alias
%
```

Comment: thaks it works now, although I am certain i tested whith the semicolon.
it's there a way to hide the output of the grep thing? if i have it in this way in .zshrc it prints "clear: alias" in every new shell

Comment: just appending `>/dev/null 2&>1` before ';' fixes it

Comment: `grep -q "alias"`, but there's no need for `grep` at all. `if alias clear > /dev/null; then unalias clear; fi` or `alias clear > /dev/null && unalias clear`.

Comment: Or skip the check altogether and just ignore the error if `unalias clear` fails.

Comment: @LuanVitor : For hiding the output of `grep`, I wouldn't use redirection (which also would hide error messages), but would simply use `grep -Fq`.